# PHP string / date replace regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have string in following format 07_Dec_2010, I need to convert it to 07 Dec, 2010

How can I achieve following using single statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `explode` function as:

```
$dt = '07_Dec_2010';

list($d,$m,$y) = explode('_',$dt);    // split on underscore.
$dt_new = $d.' '.$m.','.$y;           // glue the pieces.
```

You can also do it using a single call to `preg_replace` as:

```
$dt_new = preg_replace(array('/_/','/_/'),array(' ',','),$dt,1);
```

Or also as:

```
$dt_new = preg_replace('/^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$/',"$1 $2,$3",$dt);
```

[**Ideone link**](http://www.ideone.com/nM3ev)

Comment: I like your first one, very clean.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PHP 5.3, you could also use the following to a) parse the date string and b) format it however you like:

```
$formatted = date_create_from_format('d_M_Y', '07_Dec_2010')->format('d M, Y');
```

<sup>(`date_create_from_format()` could also be `DateTime::createFromFormat()`)</sup>

If you're not using 5.3 yet, you can use the following a) convert your string into a format that `strtotime()` understands, then b) format it however you like:

```
$formatted = date('d M, Y', strtotime(str_replace('_', '-', '07_Dec_2010')));
```

All that said, the other answers are fine if you just want to move portions of the string around.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_date = preg_replace('/(\d+)_(\w+)_(\d+)/', '${1} ${2}, ${3}', $date);
```

Arrange ${1}, ${2}, ${3} as you like